# MongoDB's location based sharding and zones vs Couchbase's Id based sharding

Tags: mongodb, couchbase, sharding

I'm comparing Couchbase and MongoDB for my application. I'll use Redis as a secondary database to just store geopoints and Couchbase or MongoDB as primary database for every other data. In this case I do want the data to be close to user but also want the data to be available when the user goes to another location. In this case there are 2 options.

1. Use MongoDB's location based sharding and zones. It is pretty sweet
   but it won't offer the performance of Couchbase and if a user
   permanently moves to another country it'll be cumbersome to import
   the document into that Shard. To my knowledge I didn't find a way to
   automate that. If there is please correct me.
2. Use Couchbase's
   default sharding but then the data won't be closer to the user. To
   my knowledge there's no way to Shard data based on location but
   correct me if I'm wrong.

in a case when developing a uber like app which one is preferred to store user data?

Comment: If you decide to go with Couchbase, you probably don't need Redis. Couchbase has a built-in memory first (and/or memory only) architecture.

Comment: @MatthewGroves that is great news but I haven't found any way to do geoQury using N1QL, I've only found REST. is there a N1QL way to go geoquery?

Comment: How are you doing GeoQuery with REST? But anyway, Couchbase's best tool for geo query (distance, bounding box, polygon) is actually the built-in Full Text Search (FTS) engine, which you can also access via N1QL if you need to!

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood a little bit but now that I read it using FTS for geoquery with N1QL makes Couchbase powerful.

Answer (score 1):

For Couchbase, If you want data closer to users (i.e. you want to use multiple data centers), then you probably want to use **multiple Couchbase clusters** (one cluster in a west data center, one in an east data center, for instance). You can use Couchbase's [XDCR](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/xdcr-overview.html) to sync data between the clusters.

Further, if you want to "geofence" data so that it doesn't get replicated (say you want to keep Europe-specific data in your Europe data center), Couchbase's XDCR has an [advanced filtering mechanism](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/xdcr-filtering.html) to prevent certain data from syncing. This would solve your "a user moves to a different country" problem.

Comment: My problem is not quite that. I want the data to be geofenced as long it's not being queried from other location. Suppose someone moves from UK to US. Then I want that whenever the UK data is being requested the US cluster will check if it has that data, if not it'll fetch that data from UK cluster. I read about XDCR and it's quite great but I'm guessing it'll copy the whole data to another cluster which is not what I really want.

Comment: With filtering, XDCR will copy only the data that you specify in the filter.